# "circle" inequality relation with triangle inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried googling this term, but irrelevant results came up.
The context is that we learnt the triangle inequality:
$\forall z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, $|w+z| \leq |w| + |z|$.

My notes then say:
"A variation of the triangle inequality sometimes called the **circle** inequality is:
$\forall w,z \in \mathbb{C}$, $||w| - |z|| \leq |w-z|$.

my question is; why would it be called the circle inequality? What relevance does it have with a circle?

Comment: I've always heard the second inequality in question referred to as the "reverse triangle inequality." Not sure why one would call it the circle inequality (maybe circle is the 'opposite' of a triangle?).

Comment: Ah I see. Curious to see why they called it that; since it might give some good intuition (and graphical interpretation, which is how I remember the triangle inequality).

Comment: I can't find any relevant occurrence of that "circle inequality".

Comment: I see four circles in the formula: two centered at the origin, with radii $|w|$ and $|z|$, one centered at $w$ passing through $z$ and one centered at $z$ passing through $w$. The (common) radius of the last two exceeds the difference of the first two radii. But that's all I can say.

Comment: $ AB \geq AC+CB $ on circle.

Comment: Maybe a circle centered at z and a point w on the circle.  The RHS is the radius of the circle.  The LHS is the magnitude of difference of the magnitudes, from the origin, of the center point and the point on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two vectors, w and z, that share the same position, O say, at one of their ends. Then one can draw a circle centred at O with radius |z|, that circumscribes the vector z. Similarly, one can draw a circle centred at O of radius |w| that circumscribes the vector w.

Without loss of generality, assume that |z| is less than or equal to |w|.

Now consider the vector w-z. The smallest possible value for |w-z| occurs when the vector z sits atop the vector w (with both pointing in the same direction): the value of |w-z|, in that case, would be ||w|-|z||.